Can I find prices/time that intersect Bollinger Bands in QuestDB?
I'm trying to build a simple trading signal finder, buy when the price goes below 60 days moving average - 2 standard deviations, and sell when the price is above 60 days moving average + 2 standard deviations. The table schema is similar to what is used in questdb demo:
CREATE TABLE "trades" (
  symbol SYMBOL,
  side SYMBOL,
  price DOUBLE,
  amount DOUBLE,
  timestamp TIMESTAMP
) timestamp (timestamp);

Can I query to get back timestamp, price, buy/sell signal indicator using SQL?
